# Can't load bitmap photo from Uri sent by intent to choose image from gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I can't load bitmap photo using uri sent by intent to choose an image from the gallery.
Error message:

```
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/78476 from pid=3693, uid=10246 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1629)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1117)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:955)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:675)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:876)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at lcukerd.com.stufflist.showList.onResume(showList.java:235)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1326)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6338)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
03-18 21:16:12.810 3693-3693/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Intent creation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_FILE);
```

ActivityResult snippet that concerns with this part:

```
 else if (requestCode==SELECT_FILE)
        {
            if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {

                photoURI = data.getData();
                Log.d("Gallery call","opened with result " + photoURI.toString());

            }
            else {
                Log.e("Gallery call", "Failed");
                photoURI = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

initializing bitmap where the error occurs:

```
if(photoURI!=null) {
                try {

                    Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(photoURI));
                    Log.d("Size of image", "width:"+photo.getWidth()+" height:"+photo.getHeight());

                    BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo);        //Don't ask why , it is required for my code
                    Eimage.setBackground(ob);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Couldn't Load",name+" "+photoURI);
                }
            }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lcukerd.com.stufflist">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".addItem" />

        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false" />

        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
            android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="lcukerd.com.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".showList"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".orderevent"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".orderitem"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am storing uri as String in SQL and then reading it before initializing bitmap. Also, the Uri sent by intent is correct I have checked it.
please help me solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move your `<uses-feature>` and `<uses-permission>` elements to their correct location: *outside* the `<application>` element (typically above the `<application>` element).
2. You cannot save the `Uri` to your database. While that may work for a `Uri` with a `file` scheme, it will not work for a `Uri` with a `content` scheme. [You only have rights to that content for a brief time, not indefinitely](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). If you need access to the image for the long term, you need to make a copy of that image to a file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`).
3. Do not load bitmaps on the main application thread. Use [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46).
4. Once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to 23 or higher, you need to handle [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
5. You cannot hold the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission, so just remove that.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a copy of image and then try to load. Yeah, I will be shifting loading bitmap to background thread later.

Comment: I am testing my app on API 23 and handling does not seem to be required once I have declared in manifest.xml . I mean I don't get any error or warnings.

Comment: @lcukerd: If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need to deal with runtime permissions... if you want to use those permissions. In your case, if you are getting `content` `Uri` values back, you may not need those permissions.